# How to implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowlayout's sizeForItemAtIndexPath with Async images?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowlayout`'s `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` similar to this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1

The problem I have is that my photos are downloaded via an async call on the web, so when `sizeForItemAtItemPath` is called, my images haven't loaded yet.  In other words, the code below crashes on imageArray.  How can I delay the method until my images are loaded? I've also tried using a hardcoded with and height value if no images are available, but then I only return those hardcoded values, i.e. `sizeForItemAtIdexPath` doesn't seem to get called again after the images are loaded.

```
func pinImageForIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UIImage {
        return imageArray[indexPath.row]
    }



}

extension PinCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    //1
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

            let pinImage =  pinImageForIndexPath(indexPath)
            //2
            if var size = pinImage.size as? CGSize {
                size.width += 10
                size.height += 10
                return size
            }
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    //3
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
            return sectionInsets
    }
}



override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PinCollectionViewCell

   cell.pinImage?.pin_updateWithProgress = true
   cell.pinImage?.image = nil

    var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    actInd.frame = cell.pinImage.bounds
    actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
    actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle =
        UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    cell.addSubview(actInd)
    actInd.startAnimating()


    if let pinImageURL = self.pins[indexPath.row].largestImage().url {


        cell.pinImage?.pin_setImageFromURL(pinImageURL, completion: ({ (result : PINRemoteImageManagerResult) -> Void in


            actInd.stopAnimating()
            if let image = result.image {
                self.imageArray.append(image)
            }

            self.collectionView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])

        }))


    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Is the code  above the corrected answer with reloadItemsAtIndexPath?

Comment: @user805981 it's unnecessary..what I figured out is that I was caching attributes in my `prepareLayout` inside the PinterestLayout from the RW tutorial.  I simply commented out the line `//if cache.isEmpty {` so that new attributes would be set when the image was set.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you should return some hardcoded values until you haven't loaded image. Strictly saying, you should display some predefined placeholder for not yet loaded image.

When your image get loaded (when async download operation successfully completes), you should call [-reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:) on collection view with index path's of those cells, images for which are available.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure I understand what get's passed into `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths`? Currently I have it inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` because that's where my images are downloaded (using PINRemoteImage framework), and I pass it `[indexPath]` but it crashes

Comment: You have to pass there indexPathes of cells, that you have images ready for. 
I can't tell you the reason of crash without seeing code.

Comment: I added my `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: Thank you, I think the problem may have been I was returning image sizes that were larger than my cell.